# File operations using the file size in Ballerina

Tags: file, filesize, ballerina

I am new to Ballerina and am trying to create a file using a specific file size. Tried searching through the documentations but couldn't find a suitable solution. Is there any way that I can create, write a file by specifying the file size instead of the file content.

If I am to specify content and create file, then for different file sizes I would need to construct different set of content accordingly. Is there any suitable function or method to do this functionality using Ballerina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using a loop structure to create a buffer of byte[] with the required length which in this scenario would be the file size.

I am sharing the code segment so someone else would find it useful.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {

    // Create an empty buffer of size 100 bytes

    byte[] buffer = [];
    byte onebyte = 1;
    int filesize = 100;

    // for loop to write the buffer to the file
    foreach int i in 1 ... filesize {
        buffer[i] = onebyte;
    }

    return check io:fileWriteBytes("file-100.txt", buffer);
}
```

Thank you for the valuable comments. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care the content of the file when creating it, you can create a byte array of the size you want, and write that byte array to a file.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {
    byte[1024] bytes = [];
    check io:fileWriteBytes("sample", bytes);
}
```

Using the `byte[1024]` you define a byte array of 1024 elements, which will be initialized using `0`s. Then it is written to the file.
This will create a file of the size of `1024 bytes`. Then you can overwrite the file later.

Comment: Thank you. But if I want to dynamically assign the file size, then this doesn't work isn't it? `byte[filesize] bytes = []` where the filesize is an int will not work as it only allows const values. Do you have a solution for this issue?

Comment: In that case, you can populate an array of the desired size using a loop.

Comment: yeah. thank you. I resolved the issue using a loop to create a byte array. I'll add the code snippet used for that as an answer to this question as well.